# Error installing pillow on Mac OS X El Capitan:

Tags: macos, pip, python-imaging-library

During installation of Pillow library I had this error and I can't solve. How can I do it?

I executed:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

The error is:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 337, in run

    self.build_extensions()

File "/private/var/folders/tj/cm2crntx36s3stmy1sytp_rh0000gn/T/pip_build_Joan/Pillow/setup.py", line 512, in build_extensions

    ' using --disable-%s, aborting' % (f, f))

ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/tj/cm2crntx36s3stmy1sytp_rh0000gn/T/pip_build_Joan/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/tj/cm2crntx36s3stmy1sytp_rh0000gn/T/pip-Q1zgvI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/tj/cm2crntx36s3stmy1sytp_rh0000gn/T/pip_build_Joan/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/tj/cm2crntx36s3stmy1sytp_rh0000gn/T/tmpKTHfju
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed with this flag and it works, with this option is not possible use jpeg files:

```
sudo pip install pillow --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--disable-jpeg"
```

Comment: Does that mean your installed version of pillow can't read (or write) JPG files? That's pretty limiting :-(

Comment: @MichielOvertoom Yes it means this but in my case I only use .png for me It's not a problem.